# applicationDidBecomeActive to return to home page

Tags: iphone, ios

Using storyboard and a `UINavigationController` my app has many `UIViewControllers`. The initial `UIViewController` is named viewController and is a kind of home page.

If the user leaves the app and returns, I always want the user always to return to the home page (`UIViewController`) not the last view before leaving. In my `appDelegate`, how do I call/display my home page (`UIViewController`) with the `applicationDidBecomeActive:`  ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your root view controller for the app is a navigation controller then you can do as Marcin Kuptel states, here is a solution for your context.

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
 {
   UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
   [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 }
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help - Oliver,s answer worked best for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated: NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check it.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
ViewController *lvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
self.window.rootViewController = lvc;
```

Put this code in applicationDidBecomeActive method.

Answer (score 1):

Your **applicationDidBecomeActive:** can be called for several reasons such as comes to the active state after **temporary interruptions** (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) not only for the transition from background to the foreground. I think in your it is better to put the code suggested by others  inside **applicationWillEnterForeground:**

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
   UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
   [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 }
```